# Counting the Omer non-verbally

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, speech-talking, handicap-disabled-impair

If someone who is chayav in mitzvot does not have the ability to speak, (say, for example, he lost his tongue in a freak tennis accident,) can he count the Omer non-verbally, through sign language, writing, or by thinking it?

This question would apply to all mitzvot deorayta (biblical commandments) that require speech.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76392/does-texting-count-as-speech